# C# picturebox and timer

Tags: c#, timer, picturebox

I am trying to create a car game using pictureboxes and timers

Here is my code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    PictureBox car = new PictureBox();
    Timer t = new Timer();

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Right arrow key
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Right) && carPlayer.Location.X < 300)
        {
            int x = carPlayer.Location.X + 5;
            int y = carPlayer.Location.Y;
            int width = carPlayer.Size.Width;
            int height = carPlayer.Size.Height;
            carPlayer.SetBounds(x, y, width, height);
        }

        //Left arrow key
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Left) && carPlayer.Location.X > 35)
        {
            int x = carPlayer.Location.X - 5;
            int y = carPlayer.Location.Y;
            int width = carPlayer.Size.Width;
            int height = carPlayer.Size.Height;
            carPlayer.SetBounds(x, y, width, height);
        }

        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Space))
        {
            spawnCar();
        }
    }


    void spawnCar()
    {
        string[] cars = { "data/car_red.png", "data/car_blue.png", "data/car_green.png", "data/car_grey.png" };
        Random rand = new Random();
        car.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        car.Image = Image.FromFile(cars[rand.Next(0, 4)]);
        car.Visible = true;

        if (rand.Next(0,2) == 0)
        {
            car.SetBounds(100, 10, 50, 85);
        }
        else
        {
            car.SetBounds(250, 10, 50, 85);
        }

        this.Controls.Add(car);
        car.BringToFront();

        t.Interval = 1;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (car.Bounds.IntersectsWith(carPlayer.Bounds))
        {
            t.Stop();
            car.Image = Image.FromFile("data/car_wreck.png");
            carPlayer.Image = Image.FromFile("data/player_wreck.png");
        }
        if (car.Bounds.Y > 340)
        {
            t.Stop();
            this.Controls.Remove(car);
        }
        else
        {
            car.Top++;
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhCgY.png

Now when I press space once the car appears at the top and moves down slowly and disappears on reaching the bottom but when I press space multiple time the speed of the car gets faster and faster .
Anyone please help me make the car move at same speed everytime it is created.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a PictureBox to make a game. If you absolutely must use WinForms, then use a Panel and the OnPaint event at least. Also, have a read up on Double Buffering

Comment: I know this is not the best way to make a game but its just for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are registering a new `Tick` event handler with each car spawn, you only want to do this once. However, there isn't an easy way to check if a handler has been assigned yet so I would recommend using a global flag...

```
//at class level
bool eventSet = false;

//in spawn method
t.Interval = 1;
if(!eventSet)//check if no handler assigned yet
{
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    eventSet = true;
}
t.Start();
```

Alternatively, you could attempt to remove the handler before assigning...

```
//in spawn method
t.Interval = 1;
t.Tick -= new EventHandler(t_Tick);//remove previous one if it exists
t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
t.Start();
```

Comment: Its not working I get this error and it wont compile.
Error 1 The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Tick' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: @user3678586: I have added an alternative which may be simpler, assuming it works